Enumerable Range Indices formatting using dotnet format
I'm using dotnet format to format my code, have rules in .editorConfig.
Problem I have is I don't seem to find the formatting rule that formats the Enumerable Range Indices, talking about the .. operator.
Anyone knows, what editor config rule this uses for formatting, the default behavior it seems to add a whitespace after the operator.
I tried to use the default, or even the empty .editorConfig, still the issue persist so its not my settings. It appears that it uses some default setting.
Before running dotnet format:
var myData = [..List1, ..List1];
After running dotnet format:
var myData = [.. List1, .. List1];
I want it to stay like the before running dotnet format
